# Opening a word document to a specific point in c# windows form application

Tags: c#, ms-word

First things first, I have to admit I am a very novice c# user. I've got a project I'm trying to work on, and basically I just google how to fix the problems I have as I encounter them. I don't have much background in c#, so please excuse my ignorance. Also, if it makes a difference, I am using c# 2010 express (4.0).

I want to have a button on my form open a word document at a specific part of the document. For example, word uses headings to structure the table of contents. Suppose I want to jump to the "Getting Started" section. Should I use the Browser or Range object? I was reading about the Range object, but couldn't figure out if I should use wdGoToHeading or wdGoToSection. I'd prefer to use wdGoToHeading (wdGoToSection seems I would have to add in section breaks which would be a hassle) if it would allow me to specify a specific heading to open the document to, but from reading what I could find, it seems that I can only specify it to open to "Heading 1" rather than a "Getting Started" section that is using Heading 1. Is this wrong? Would I use wdGoToAbsolute and then use count = n to go to the nth heading, or would that take me to "Heading n"?

Currently, all I have is:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notes.docx");
```

to open the document to the beginning of the document.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.0 has a better and much improved office interop. I suggest you to look into it before taking the wrong path. Take a look at this example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317478.aspx

For reading word document in C# take a look at this article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Globalking/fileAccessingusingcsharp02242006050207AM/fileAccessingusingcsharp.aspx?ArticleID=44e79e38-0cdc-4e5e-8574-63572d8cc112. This example uses the old office interops!!

This is in .NET 4.0: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/accessing-microsoft-office-interop-objects-using-C-Sharp-4-0/

I hope it gives yo some idea.